# mysqldump is not dumping the tables in the database in MariaDB 5.5

Tags: linux, mysql, mariadb

I am using the following command.

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --single-transaction   --flush-logs --create-options -B --default-character-set=utf8  --routines  --max_allowed_packet=1048576  -u root -p --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 'mydatabase' > mydump.DUMP
```

This is the output of the dump

```
[root@centostemp bin]# cat mydump.DUMP

-- MySQL dump 10.14  Distrib 5.5.41-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: mydatabase
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.5.41-MariaDB
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
-- Dump completed on 2016-07-18 11:26:33
```

I have few tables and views in this database. But mysqldump has only the above lines I have pasted. It has no information about the tables or views.

Comment: See if removing the whitespace here `--max_allowed_packet  =1048576` helps.

Comment: Sorry, got that space when I had copy pasted the query. Else there is no space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was a bug from mariadb when --single-transaction is used with mysqldump. It is fixed now.

Comment: Removing `--single-transaction` worked for me, too (I am using MySQL).